# Recover a tmux session that tmux insists isn't running

Tags: tmux

I have had a tmux session running for a while, and I can see it's running using `pstree`:

```
systemd─┬─accounts-daemon───2*[{accounts-daemon}]
        ├─2*[agetty]
        ├─containerd───11*[{containerd}]
        ├─cron
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─4*[dd]
        ├─dockerd───12*[{dockerd}]
        ├─fail2ban-server───2*[{fail2ban-server}]
        ├─irqbalance───{irqbalance}
        ├─networkd-dispat
        ├─polkitd───2*[{polkitd}]
        ├─qemu-ga
        ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
        ├─ssh-agent
        ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
        ├─systemd───(sd-pam)
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-network
        ├─systemd-resolve
        ├─systemd-timesyn───{systemd-timesyn}
        ├─systemd-udevd
        ├─tmux: server─┬─bash───find_cli
        │              └─3*[bash]
        └─unattended-upgr───{unattended-upgr}
```

(it's down the bottom there)

However, `tmux` itself insists there are no sessions:

```bsh
$ tmux attach
no sessions
$ tmux ls
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default
```

Is there any way to recover a tmux session in this situation?

Comment: Is it actually running as the current user, or as some other user?

Comment: Or with a non-default socket. See `man 1 tmux`, options `-L` and `-S`. Can it be the case? On the other hand, if you started a server in a non-default way, you would probably know.

Comment: Looks like that tmux is being run by another user on the system. See if any other user is logged into the system. use `w`

Comment: @GMaster They might have started `tmux` as root, disconnected from it, and forgotten about it.

Comment: Yes it must be running as me (`ubuntu`), because `ps -aux` returns `ubuntu   23508  0.8  0.0  19116  7696 ?        Ss   Mar02 673:09 tmux`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the socket has been removed you should be able to [make tmux recreate it](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#tmux-says-no-sessions-when-i-try-to-attach-but-i-definitely-had-sessions) with `pkill -USR1 tmux`.

Comment: I still have a process running under that tmux session which I can't afford to cancel. Will this affect the child process?

Comment: It shouldn't do.

Comment: I don't know why this works, but it does. I was able to `tmux attach` immediately after running that command.

Comment: Something removed your tmux socket in `/tmp` and sending this signal to the tmux server asks it to create it again.

Comment: Ah, so `USR1` is a program-defined signal that tmux uses as a signal to recreate the socket. `pkill` here isn't being used to kill the process, but rather send `USR1` to tmux.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: I can confirm I had exactly the same issue and this solution worked without killing the running processes

Comment: This works! Thank you! 

For future readers, it seems that I needed to avoid creating a new tmux session when I run the above commands, i.e., when running the above commands, the tmux ls should shoud the `no server running on /tmp/tmux-*/default` otherwise it refuse to recover the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

If `ps` or other process information commands show that `tmux` is still running but doesn't respond properly to the `tmux attach` command, you might be able to make tmux interactive again by sending a SIGUSR1 signal to the tmux server.

This can be done, as mentioned in the answer above, by using the `pkill -USR1 tmux` command. You can then run the `tmux attach` command again to see if you can now interact with tmux.

An alternative to the machine-gun method of using `pkill` is to use a specific PID number with `kill`. The command template would be quite similar to the `pkill` method save for the use of a PID number rather than a program name pattern. Thus your command might look like the following:

$ kill -USR1 NNNN

You can get the NNNN by carefully reading the output of `ps ax | grep tmux`. This assumes you have several tmux instances running. Otherwise (i.e. if you're running only one tmux instance), it's indeed easier to `pkill` tmux.

As a side note, I find both `pkill` and `killall` to be pretty dangerous, especially when used as root.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/449756)

Comment: Neither does the original answer directly answer the question. But if you insist, I've edited my answer.